# SharePoint Online - Calculated column to find earliest date of another column

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-columns, sharepoint-list

I have a list that contains tasks for a project. Each task has a start date which is independent of all the other tasks' start dates. For example:

| Task | Start Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-08-01 |
| 2 | 2022-08-03 |
| 3 | 2022-08-10 |

I would like to create a calculated column that finds the earliest start date and applies it to all items in the list. For example:

| Task | Start Date | Earliest Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-08-01 | 2022-08-01 |
| 2 | 2022-08-03 | 2022-08-01 |
| 3 | 2022-08-10 | 2022-08-01 |

However, when I create the calculated column as `=MIN([StartDate])`, it only references the dates within each item and not the dates from all items in the list (i.e., column). Giving me this:

| Task | Start Date | Earliest Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-08-01 | 2022-08-01 |
| 2 | 2022-08-03 | 2022-08-03 |
| 3 | 2022-08-10 | 2022-08-10 |

Do I need to use different syntax when creating a calculated column to force SharePoint to look across items when doing the calculation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known limitation of SharePoint calculated columns.

Calculated column formula can only reference the column values from same list item/row. It cannot access column values (data) from other list items/rows.